# Optimizing code from spectral subtraction algorithm

Tags: java, optimization, android, mathematics, matrix

This is part of the code from a spectral subtraction algorithm.  I'm trying to optimize it for Android.

**Matlab code:**

```
function Seg=segment(signal,W,SP,Window)

% SEGMENT chops a signal to overlapping windowed segments
% A= SEGMENT(X,W,SP,WIN) returns a matrix which its columns are segmented
% and windowed frames of the input one dimentional signal, X. W is the
% number of samples per window, default value W=256. SP is the shift
% percentage, default value SP=0.4. WIN is the window that is multiplied by
% each segment and its length should be W. the default window is hamming
% window.
% 06-Sep-04
% Esfandiar Zavarehei

if nargin<3
    SP=.4;
end
if nargin<2
    W=256;
end
if nargin<4
    Window=hamming(W);
end
Window=Window(:); %make it a column vector

L=length(signal);
SP=fix(W.*SP);
N=fix((L-W)/SP +1); %number of segments

Index=(repmat(1:W,N,1)+repmat((0:(N-1))'*SP,1,W))';
hw=repmat(Window,1,N);
Seg=signal(Index).*hw;
```

**Java code:**

```
public class MatrixAndSegments 
{
    public int numberOfSegments;
    public double[][] res;

    public MatrixAndSegments(int numberOfSegments,double[][] res)
    {
        this.numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments;
        this.res = res;
    }
}



public MatrixAndSegments segment (double[] signal_in,int samplesPerWindow, double        shiftPercentage, double[] window)
{
    //default shiftPercentage = 0.4
    //default samplesPerWindow = 256  //W
    //default window = hanning 


    int L = signal_in.length;
    shiftPercentage = fix(samplesPerWindow * shiftPercentage); //SP
    int numberOfSegments = fix ( (L - samplesPerWindow)/ shiftPercentage + 1); //N

    double[][] reprowMatrix =  reprowtrans(samplesPerWindow,numberOfSegments);
    double[][] repcolMatrix = repcoltrans(numberOfSegments, shiftPercentage,samplesPerWindow );

    //Index=(repmat(1:W,N,1)+repmat((0:(N-1))'*SP,1,W))';
    double[][] index = new double[samplesPerWindow+1][numberOfSegments+1];

    for (int x = 1;  x < samplesPerWindow+1; x++ )
    {
        for (int y = 1 ; y < numberOfSegments + 1; y++) //numberOfSegments was 3
        {
             index[x][y] = reprowMatrix[x][y] + repcolMatrix[x][y];
        }
    }

    //hamming window
    double[] hammingWindow = this.HammingWindow(samplesPerWindow);
    double[][] HW = repvector(hammingWindow, numberOfSegments);

    double[][] seg = new double[samplesPerWindow][numberOfSegments];
    for (int y = 1 ; y < numberOfSegments + 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < samplesPerWindow+1; x++)
        {
            seg[x-1][y-1] = signal_in[ (int)index[x][y]-1 ] * HW[x-1][y-1]; 
        }
    }
    MatrixAndSegments Matrixseg = new MatrixAndSegments(numberOfSegments,seg);
    return Matrixseg;

}


public int fix(double val) {
    if (val < 0) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(val);
    }
    return (int) Math.floor(val);
}

public double[][] repvector(double[] vec, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[vec.length][replications];

    for (int x = 0; x < vec.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < replications; y++) {
            result[x][y] = vec[x];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public double[][] reprowtrans(int end, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[end +1][replications+1];

    for (int x = 1; x <= end; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= replications; y++) {
            result[x][y] = x ;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

 public double[][] repcoltrans(int end, double multiplier, int replications)
{
    double[][] result = new double[replications+1][end+1];

    for (int x = 1; x <= replications; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= end ; y++) {
            result[x][y] = (y-1)*multiplier;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

 public double[] HammingWindow(int size)
{
    double[] window = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        window[i] =  0.54-0.46 * (Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * i / (size-1)));
    }
    return window;
}
```

Comment: you could start by flattening your `double[][]` to `double[]`. If every little bit counts, there's some RAM and speed you can gain by it.

Comment: does it need optimization for android? have you profiled the code?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a clue about spectral subtraction, so just some minor, general notes about code:

1. > ```
   > public int fix(double val) {
   >     if (val < 0) {
   >         return (int) Math.ceil(val);
   >     }
   >     return (int) Math.floor(val);
   > }
   > ```

   It should be called [`truncate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Truncation).
2. A few variables could be renamed to follow the Java code conventions.

   - Variables, parameters:

     - `signal_in` to `inputSignal` or signal
     - `HW` to `hw`
     - `seg` maybe to `segments` or `segment` (?)
     - `Matrixseg` to `matrixSeg`
   - Methods:

     - `HammingWindow` to `calculateHammingWindow`

   (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions* and [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, 6.1 Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)).
3. This comments looks unnecessary:

   > ```
   > // hamming window
   > double[] hammingWindow = this.HammingWindow(samplesPerWindow);
   > ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)

   The `this.` prefix also unnecessary.

Comment: `hw` could have a better name. I don't know why he have `hammingWindows` and then `HW`, when it's looks like the same thing but does not represent the same data (`double[]` vs `double[][]`). Maybe switch the two name so that the one who is used more often would have a complete name ?